# GD Image Library to create transparent GIF after manipulation

Tags: php, image, gd

I am generating a dynamic image using PHP that is a PNG with transparency.

During this process, I am adding a transparent PNG logo on top of the image, also preserving its transparency.

I currently have this working just fine when I output the final product as a PNG using php `imagepng($destination)`.

However, I this image is rather larger in size due to it being a PNG and I need to convert the final output to a gif (to keep the transparency on the background image).

Here is my code:

```
$data = [
    'name' => [
        'x' => ($noBG ? 150 : 400),
        'y' => ($noBG ? 700 : 920),
        'size' => 40,
        'angle' => 0,
        'content' => $name,
    ],
    'pin' => [
        'x' => ($noBG ? 130 : 440),
        'y' => ($noBG ? 475 : 700),
        'size' => 75,
        'angle' => 0,
        'content' => implode('  ', str_split($pin)),
    ],
    'denomination' => [
        'x' => denominationPosition($denomination, $noBG),
        'y' => ($noBG ? 150 : 375),
        'size' => 70,
        'angle' => 0,
        'content' => $denomination,
    ],
    'defaultText' => [
        'x' => ($noBG ? 150 : 400),
        'y' => ($noBG ? 780 : 980),
        'size' => 30,
        'angle' => 0,
        'content' => 'It Doesn\'t Cost - It PAY$!',
    ],
    'logo' => [
        'x' => ($noBG ? 875 : 1200),
        'y' => ($noBG ? 675 : 880),
    ],
];

// Are we using the template with or without a background?
if($noBG){
    $style = 'assets/images/templateNoBG.png';
}else{
    $style = 'assets/images/template.png';
}


// Did we pass a logo?
if ($logo) {
    $src = imagecreatefrompng($logo);
}else{
    $src= imagecreatefrompng($noLogo);
}

// Transparent sponsor logo
imagealphablending($src, false);
imagesavealpha($src, true);

// Define our source image (the background)
$destination = imagecreatefrompng($style);

// Colors
$textColor = imagecolorallocate($destination, 255, 255, 255);
$regularFont = 'assets/fonts/Bungee-Regular.otf';

// Transparent background
imagealphablending($destination, true);
imagesavealpha($destination, true);

// Name
imagettftext($destination, $data['name']['size'], $data['name']['angle'], $data['name']['x'], $data['name']['y'], $textColor, $regularFont, $data['name']['content']);
// Pin
imagettftext($destination, $data['pin']['size'], $data['pin']['angle'], $data['pin']['x'], $data['pin']['y'], $textColor, $regularFont, $data['pin']['content']);
// Denomination
imagettftext($destination, $data['denomination']['size'], $data['denomination']['angle'], $data['denomination']['x'], $data['denomination']['y'], $textColor, $regularFont, '$' . $data['denomination']['content']);
// Default Text
imagettftext($destination, $data['defaultText']['size'], $data['defaultText']['angle'], $data['defaultText']['x'], $data['defaultText']['y'], $textColor, $regularFont, $data['defaultText']['content']);

// Merge the logo and template together
imagecopy($destination, $src, $data['logo']['x'], $data['logo']['y'], 0, 0, $logoWidth, $logoHeight);


// Create our header to flush the image to browser
//header("Content-type: image/png");
header("Content-type: image/gif");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache");

/**
 * Un-comment to ask to save file
 * header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="DiningCard.png"');
 */

// Render image
//imagepng($destination); // Works
imagegif($destination);

// Cleanup
imagedestroy($destination);


/**
 * Depending on the number of of numbers in the denomination,
 * pass x coordinates to help keep it in position
 */
function denominationPosition($denomination, $noBG)
{
    switch (strlen($denomination)) {
        case 1:
            return ($noBG ? 1150 : 950);
            break;
        case 2:
            return ($noBG ? 1100: 1400);
            break;
        case 3:
            return ($noBG ? 1050 : 1350);
            break;
        case 4:
            return ($noBG ? 950 : 1290);
            break;
    }

}
```

The issue I am running into is that when I use `imagegif($destination)`, the background image is losing its transparency and is all distorted.

The background of the image should be transparent but you can see the distortion and lack of alpha channel. 
[image]

When output as a `png` via `imagepng()`, all works fine.

Here is the PNG Version:

[image]

I put this up on a bitbucket repo incase anyone wants to look at the code - things like this are difficult to troubleshoot just looking at code.

https://bitbucket.org/sbbdev/cardgen/src

Any ideas on how to get the gif version working of this? The size difference between the two is essential to get working.

Comment: I don't have time to try this, but try allocating a transparent colour as the first thing you do after loading the background image like `$transp = imagecolorallocatealpha($destination,255,255,255,127);`

Comment: GIF isn't a true-colour capable format and doesn't support alpha channel transparency.  When you ask PHP to output a GIF it reduces the resource to an 8-bit (256) colour palette.  Since you've not specifically set a transparent colour via [`imagecolortransparent`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolortransparent.php) there's no transparency.

Comment: @timclutton - Care to take a stab at an answer? More than willing to award the bounty for a quick solution :)

Comment: @SBB I looked in to this a couple of days ago.  You're going to have to decide where you want to compromise: quality or size. The PNG comes out ~900KiB, and the GIF ~300KiB.  What's your use case?  Why is it important to keep the size down? Can you run a server-side optimiser?  (Simply running `templateNoBG.png` through tinypng.com reduces it from 1.02MiB to 227KiB with no apparent quality loss.)

Comment: @timclutton - my use case is that this image will be going out in email campaigns custom to each of the users. When doing some tests, there is a few second relay while his image appears and loads within the email. The gif version is there almost instantly (based on my own speed of course). Both quality and size are important in a way. Do you have any idea what tinypng is doing to the images to reduce them that i could just enable on my side?

Comment: To quote TinyPNG: '...similar colors in your image are combined. This technique is called “quantization”. By reducing the number of colors, 24-bit PNG files can be converted to much smaller 8-bit indexed color images. All unnecessary metadata is stripped too.'  PHP/GD can't do that natively, but you could try a [pngquant](https://pngquant.org/) binary, if you have access to your server and can use 'unsafe' functions like `exec()`.

Comment: @timclutton well that sounds good and looks like its what would work but unfortunately, my host does't install nor let me install these libraries. Doesn't sounds like there is a way to do this though if it can't be converted to a gif in my existing code.

Comment: Do you have ImageMagick available? Otherwise you can use tinypng via an [api](https://tinypng.com/developers/reference/php) to optimise the image before returning it to the client.  That might not be an improvement with response time though.

Comment: @timclutton I do believe that `ImageMagick` is installed on this server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [solution proposed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48307082/3775731) by @astrangeloop takes about 2.5 seconds to render on my laptop. As OP has [indicated that speed is a factor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48198399/gd-image-library-to-create-transparent-gif-after-manipulation#comment83591926_48198399) I don't think this solution works.

I propose:

- Manually optimise the assets on the server
- convert those assets to true color when opening in PHP
- render as GIF

By way of example, I optimised `templateNoBG.png` using tinypng.com, reducing the file size from 1.02MiB to 227KiB:

[image]

Since the image is now 8-bit (256 colour) we need to make it true colour when opening so that the merged images retain their colours:

```
$destination = imagecreatefrompng($style);
imagepalettetotruecolor($destination);
```

When the image is output using `imagegif` it is again reduced to 8-bit, with a much better palette selection, albeit with apparent jagged edges due to GIF only supporting binary transparency:

[image]

The resulting image is only 395KiB and generates in about 120ms on my laptop.

This is probably about the best trade-off between speed, quality and size that can be expected.

Comment: Thank you for this! I am going to try and integrate it shortly and let you know how it goes. Just out of curiosity, if I JUST started with the optimized PNG background and left everything else in place, outputting a png, will it raise the file size back up or keep it low? GIF isn't a requirement for the output format but figured a PNG was fully uncompressed so gif would have been the best result.

Comment: @SBB I wasn’t clear in my post; 395KiB was achieved with only the background image optimised. Other assets were unmodified. I think the image was ~600KiB when output as a true colour PNG.

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comments, gif is a palette-based format and doesn't support full alpha transparency. You can achieve something close to what you want by allocating a transparent colour, and then scanning through the image and setting pixels with an alpha value of 50% or more to this transparent colour before converting to gif format.

```
// Render image
//imagepng($destination); // Works
$transparent = imagecolortransparent($destination, imagecolorallocate($destination, 0, 0, 0));
$width = imagesx($destination);
$height = imagesy($destination);
for ($x = 0; $x < $width; $x++) {
    for ($y = 0; $y < $height; $y++) {
        $pixel = imagecolorsforindex($destination, imagecolorat($destination, $x, $y));
        if ($pixel['alpha'] >= 64) {
            imagesetpixel($destination, $x, $y, $transparent);
        }
    }
}
imagegif($destination);
```

Please note though that this will produce rough edges in your image, as pixels are either fully opaque or fully transparent in gif format.